# Ubuntu 16.04 - Gephi 0.9.1 unable to run

Tags: startup, crash

The first time i installed Gephi, I had some problems but then they came to an end. Two days ago, however, he decided to stop running and I can not locate the problem. I tried the solutions offered on different forums but none solved it. It basically crashes during the splash screen.

```
    java version "1.8.0_131"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Also, typing

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

it returns

```
   Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
   Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
   Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu precise InRelease  
   Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
   Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
   Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease
   Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
   Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu precise Release
   Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release                
   Reading package lists... Done                      
   N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
   W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key FAAB7C47FE58B57D8D79EE6ACE88AE67BC982EC8 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
   W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

And

```
  env | grep -i "java"
```

returns

```
  DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
  JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/alessandro/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131
  J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

Answer (score 0):

It was much simpler than I thought:

```
    rm -r .gephi
```

and it solved.